# How can I display the default dashboard of SAP B1 9.2 PL10?

Tags: sapb1

I enabled cockpit and dashboard in the company database of SAP B1 9.2 PL10 and I configured integration where everything is all right, but the problem I have is I don't see dashboard of Purchasing, Sales or Finance, what I see is the dashboard of service in my cockpit. If I click in Purchasing, Sales or Finance I get message "No Record Found".

How can I display the default dashboard of SAP B1 9.2 PL10?

Please anyone can help me

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be about programming. You could try with Super User or a SAP Community forum.

Comment: I did it Sandra, Thank you so much